# How to input a date in custom format in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a cell with this value: `Sat 24 Jan 2009 01:23:12`
I defined a custom date format: `jjj jj mmm aaaa hh:mm:ss`

[image]

.but I can't do arithmetic on this date cell. For example I can't do "CELL + 1 hour"

Comment: The only reason I can find that it wouldn't work would be that the date is actually a text. Try changing the format to general. If it doesn't become a number, it's a text, otherwise something else is wrong somewhere. I've created the custom formatting you have and have no issues with performing arithmetic on that date.

Comment: @Jerry I tried to have at A1 a cell with `Sat 27 Jan 2009 10:01:00` and at A2 to do  `=A1 + NOW()`, but I get the error: `#VALUE!`

Comment: No, add a date first to A1, using for example `Ctrl`+`;` (this should add an actual date in a standard format), *then* apply the custom formatting, *then* do the operation. If you just type that date, which is not a format understood by Excel, it'll be understood by Excel as a text value, on which arithmetic cannot be performed, causing the error.

Comment: @Jerry I see. I wanted to input it in custom formatting and Excel to detect it’s a date.

Answer (score 1):

to add an hour to time just add  +(1/24) to the formula or =cell+(1/24) in a new column

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't exactly understand a text as a date when a custom formatting is created, so the way you described it in your question is not really going to work (unless someone actually knows a way to do that). I'd suggest using a helper formula that will work for the specific format that you have:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,20)," ","-",1)," ","-",1)*1
```

If you omit the `*1` I have at the end, you should see the text I'm using before multiplying by 1 (that's where Excel attempts to convert the text to number, which is a date format that Excel can understand).

The above should give you a number with some decimals. Format it as date, with the formatting of your choice and you should be good to go. I used `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and got this:

[image]

The `MID` basically removes the weekday part, and the two `SUBSTITUTE`s replace the first 2 spaces with a dash each, and that's something Excel can understand as datetime.